# Let $f \in Map(\mathbb{Z})$ be given by $f(n) = n+1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Find all elements in $Map(\mathbb{Z})$ that commute with $f$.

Tags: group-theory, monoid

Let $f \in Map(\mathbb{Z})$ be given by $f(n) = n+1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Find all elements in $Map(\mathbb{Z})$ that commute with $f$.

I understood that I need to show $f^m$ $\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}$ commute with $f$. For the positive integer $m$ it is easy but what can I do for negative integers? It would mean to find the inverse I guess. Also how do I show that any other element of $Map(\mathbb{Z})$ doesn't commute with $f$?

Please some help..!!

Edit : I think for the negative index $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f^{-m}(n) = n -m$, it can also be shown easily that for all integer $m$, $f$ commutes with $f^m$.

Comment: What is Map$(\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: It's not also mentioned clearly but I think it means the collection of all functions on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Well, say $g$ commutes with $f$.  Deduce that $g(n+1)=g(n)+1$ for all $n$.  Now let $g(0)=m$.  Show, inductively, that $g(n)=n+m$ for all $n$

Comment: Pick $g \colon \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ and suppose that $g\circ f = f \circ g$. Then for $n$ integer, we have $g \circ f^n =f^n \circ g$. Evaluate this last functional equality at $0$ . Edit: I'm late, this is exactly what @lulu is suggesting.

Comment: Yes.  My method, if you can push it through, will show that "$g$ commutes with $f$ if and only if $g(n)=n+g(0)$ for all $n$".  Note, for instance, that $g(n+1)=g(n)+1\implies g(1)=g(0)+1$. Now show that $g(2)=g(0)+2$.  Now use induction to show that $g(n)=n+g(0)$ for natural numbers $n$.  Now do the same for the negative integers.

Comment: @lulu I understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g$ commute with $f$, then $g(f(n))=f(g(n))$, which implies $g(n+1)=g(n)+1$, so we only need to know one value of $g$ to determine the function. If $g(0)=m$ then $g(n)=m+n$ and so the set of functions commuting with $f$ is:
$$\lbrace g\in Map(\mathbb{Z})\mid g(n)=n+m \forall n\in\mathbb{Z} \text{ for some } m\in\mathbb{Z}\rbrace$$

Comment: So $g=f^m$?....